# I can't figure this line out in Scala: s"label($name)"

Tags: scala

I've looked for this in other answers but it seems that the symbol `$` trips the search engines up, and it's hard to look for "what is that `s` doing". I've tried putting `$` in quotes but I guess I'm doing something wrong.

Anyway, I have this method inside of a class:

```
class Label(val name: String) {
  override def toString = s"Label($name)"
}
```

And there's a lot of confusion here.

What is that `s` right before the quotation marks? From what I can understand, the class `Label` receives a String in its construction, so I'm not even sure why a `toString` method is necessary.

Seems pretty obvious that `$name` is the name variable that holds the `String` Label received, but why the `$`? I suspect that it has something to do with the variable being a field? Local vs global? But looking for this on google led me nowhere. Could someone please decipher this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is called string interpolation.

The `s` is telling Scala to substitute any variables that are encountered in the string.

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html

In terms of helping you search, I know that it can be annoying to figure out the best way to search for these kind of things. In this case, if you search for "scala s string function" the first 2 results in Google give you the answer you need.